# How to remove sun's reflection on a photo using image processing

Tags: python, image-processing

I have multiple grayscale images in which each image has the sun's reflection or also known as glare as a bright glaring spot. It looks like a bright white blob which I want to remove. It is basically the front portion of a car image when the sun's reflection falls on the front steel grill of the car.

I want to remove this reflection as much as possible. I would appreciate if anyone can point me to a good algorithm , preferably in Python, that I can leverage to remove this glare and pre-process as much as possible.

I tried the approach of applying a threshold to the image pixels and then setting anything that is above 200 to a value of 128. It doesn't work very well because there are other parts of the image that contains white and those get affected.

Comment: have you attempted anything at all?

Comment: @depperm I just edited the question with one of my attempt.

Comment: add code, not just an explanation of what you did

Comment: If you reduce an intensely-focused glare, what do you expect to see in its place? If it's just a bit highlighted then there are algorithms to reduce the highlighting and increase what's left, but an area with a direct reflection of the sun probably doesn't contain any other data - you'd have to reconstruct it based on the surroundings. In a nutshell, it's hard.

Comment: @depperm Alright, I will add some code too. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: And a sample image please together with another image where you might draw by hand in red to indicate the region(s) you would like to remove.

Answer (score 0):

do not forget to add some sample images ,...

**I would try first identify the sun spot**

- by intensity and the shape of graph `intensity=f(distance from spot middle)`
- it may have a distinct shape that could be used to identify the spot more reliably

**After that I would bleed colors**

- from spot outer area to the its inside
- recoloring the spot with its surrounding color ...
- by finding all spot pixels that are next to non spot pixels
- recoloring them to average of neighboring non spot pixels
- and clearing them in spot mask
- looping this until no spot pixel in mask is left

**[notes]**

- But without any input images to test is this just a theory
- also if you have the source RGB image not just gray the color patterns can may be also be used to help identify the spots
- by checking for saturation of white and or some rainbow like pattern